# Issue with @babel import _Object$defineProperty from "../../core-js/object/define-property";

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to configurate my NodeJs project. If I add any async/await in the code, the following error appears:

```
1] import _Object$defineProperty from "../../core-js/object/define-property";
[1]        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[1] 
[1] SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

My .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": true
        },
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator"]
}
```

My webpack.config.js is

```
const path = require("path")
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")

const config = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  target: "node",
  externals: [nodeExternals()], // in order to ignore all modules in node_modules folder

  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: "/client/dist/",
    chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: `${__dirname}/client/dist`
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: ["node_modules/"],
        include: [/src/],
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        },
        plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: "[name].[hash:7].[ext]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  watch: true
}

module.exports = config
```

I tried to add @babel/plugin-transform-runtime, but it did not solve my problem.
Could somebody give me the clue, what I am doing not right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `babel-polyfill` to your project, and as an entry for webpack:

`yarn add babel-polyfill -D`

and in **`webpack.config.js`**:

```
const path = require("path")
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals")

const config = {
  entry: {
    polyfill: "babel-polyfill",
    app: "./src/index.js"
  },

...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help. I cannot understand why even the error occurs in node_modules event after I have excluded it